# Reproducible brief acceleration cut-out at 65mph

Tags: honda, accord, acceleration

We recently bought a second-hand 2001 Honda Accord. Yesterday the check engine light came on while driving, and a few minutes later the acceleration momentarily cut out (resulting in a 'bump' feeling). At the time I was travelling at about 65mph. I slowed down, but eventually when nothing happened crept back up to about 65mph at which point the same thing happened again. I drove home at about 60 with no repeat of the issue.

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Getting the codes read is a great first step to diagnosing the issue. At the very least, it will most likely get you pointed in the right direction. If the check engine light comes on, there's about a 99% chance it will have a code in there just waiting to be read! Let us know :o)

Comment: what kind of revs are you seeing at 65? afaik there isn’t a speed limiter. how long since your last oil change?

Comment: @Ben Sorry for the slow reply - it's hitting just over 3000rpm at those speeds, and it looks like that's the trigger for cutout rather than the speed per se; tested by staying in a lower gear while accelerating. Oil was supposedly changed by dealer when bought (in last 6 weeks) but I'll check.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Any tips on reading the code for this model? Haven't done it before and our local garage says it's too old for them to have the correct kit (!), so it's going to be a while...

Comment: i’d say it’s a problem with the vvt system if it’s cutting out after 3000rpm. you can get the codes read at any auto parts store for free usually. check your invoice and make sure they used the correct grade of oil and a honda oil filter as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check engine light just indicates that something is wrong, but not what exactly.

Depending on the problem, cars can reduce motor power etc. to prevent further damage/unsafe conditions, but to still allow you to limb home.

Without further details, I'd say the car thinks it's not safe to drive faster and switches to this low speed mode.

Comment: Would a 2001 car be that 'smart', though?